# Azure, Oracle SQL Developer, and JDBC Driver

Tags: jdbc, azure, azure-sql-database, jtds

I have a SQL Azure database and Oracle SQL Developer. I want to connect to my Azure instance using Oracle SQL Developer. SQL Developer needs JDBC drivers to work with MSSQL databases. The jTDS driver works with SQL Developer but not with SQL Azure databases (apparently). The 4.0 version of the MS JDBC Driver works with SQL Azure but not with Oracle SQL Developer (apparently). Has anyone else been here and found a solution?

Comment: Why is it *apparent* that SQL Developer cannot work with V4.0 of the MS driver? And what exactly does *not work* mean? It's not an error message I have seen before.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem using the JTDS driver but it is required to add ssl=require

So string is like:
driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
database=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://YourSQLServer.database.windows.net:1433/YourDBName;ssl=require